# CREATE TABLE failing (wrong CQL version)

Tags: cassandra, cql3, datastax-enterprise

Creating tables failing with inet, multiple primary keys, and collections. Syntax was correct.

Error messages  don't make sense with the primary key (unmatched parens). remove that, I learned that inet won't work except in some cases.

Anything I'm doing wrong, or not understanding about using CQL3 (interfaces or syntax)?

```
CREATE TABLE session (
  'user_id' bigint,
  'admin_id' bigint,
  'session_id' varchar,
  'cache' text ,
  'created' timestamp ,
  'hits' list<timestamp>, 
  'ip' inet  , 
  PRIMARY KEY ( 'session_id' , 'user_id' )  
  );
```

The following also fails

```
CREATE TABLE 'session' (
  'user_id' bigint,
  'session_id' varchar,
  PRIMARY KEY ( 'session_id' , 'user_id' )  
  );
```

This works

```
CREATE TABLE 'session' (
  'user_id' bigint,
  'session_id' varchar PRIMARY KEY 
  );
```

The clue

```
>help TYPES

    CQL types recognized by this version of cqlsh:

      ascii
      bigint
      blob
      boolean
      counter
      decimal
      double
      float
      int
      text
      timestamp
      uuid
      varchar
      varint
```

DSE 3.0.x

**[EDIT] - turns out DSE has Cassandra 1.1.x installed.**

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**TL;DR: Collections (part of CQL3) not available yet in DSE 3.0.x**

Also worth noting, but unrelated to my issue:

Even in Datastax community edition - one needs to activate CQL3. The documentation says it should be activated by default in cqlsh

http://www.datastax.com/docs/1.2/cql_cli/using_cql

"Activating CQL 3
You activate the CQL mode in one of these ways:

- Use the DataStax Java Driver to activate CQL through the
- native/binary protocol. Start cqlsh, a Python-based command-line
  client.
- Use the set_sql_version Thrift method.
- Specify the desired CQL mode in the connect() call to the Python driver:
  *connection = cql.connect('localhost:9160', cql_version='3.0')*

The documentation there was incorrect also, should be

```
con = cql.connect('localhost', cql_version='3.0.0')
```

Also, Enterprise Opcenter doesn't yet support CQL 3 in DSE.

```
 cqlsh --cqlversion=3
```

Comment: Datastax enterprise doesn't have cql3 , so there are no collections

Comment: Adding cqlsh -3 is the same as cqlsh --cqlversion=3. It does load cql3 but still won't support collection types, inet, or multiple primary keys. My question was unclear. Sorry for confusion.